# Draggable toggle checkboxes events not firing on Chrome (JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, draggable, mousemove, touchstart

I'm trying to replicate as closely as possible the sliding toggles of iOS, using just JS and CSS.
I've found the excellent pen by @3rror404 that does exactly that [here](https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/PBYKbO).

While it works perfectly in iOS Safari , it does react just to clicks and not to drags in Chrome (both Desktop and Android) and I don't understand why. I even added mouseup/mousedown/mousemove events, but still a no go..

```
for (let i = 0; i < switches.length; i++) {

  const switchEl = switches[i];

  switchEl.draggable = true;

  ['dragstart', 'touchstart','mousedown'].forEach(function(e) {
    switchEl.addEventListener(e, onDragStart);
  });

  ['dragover', 'touchmove','mousemove'].forEach(function(e) {
    switchEl.addEventListener(e, onDragOver);
  });

  ['dragend', 'touchend','mouseup'].forEach(function(e) {
    switchEl.addEventListener(e, onDragEnd);
  });

}
```

see my edited pen here: https://codepen.io/azerty1234/pen/BajLqgN

any idea why this happens or possible fixes? Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried the pen in Chrome 83.0.4103.106 and dragging works fine.

Comment: I've tried it and it feels very clunky on Chrome 83.0.4103.61.

Comment: @dehart: wow, that's strange: I've tried on Chrome 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Win10 and it works using Mouse but does not in Dev mode using device emulation Also, mouse events go crazy after the first click and toggle triggers on mouseover afterwards. Nor does it work (dragging) on Chrome 83 on Android

Comment: @Daan: any improvement is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bug in the pen.

It adds the same event handler for `dragstart` and `touchstart`
Chrome (in mobile mode) fires the `touchstart` event.

The `touchstart` event does not have a `pageX` and `pageY` variable (line 64 and 65)

It does have `evt.touches[0].pageX` and `evt.touches[0].pageY`

You should check if `evt.type` equals 'touchstart' or not:

```
function onDragStart(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  const x = (evt.type == 'touchstart') ? evt.touches[0].pageX : evt.pageX,
        y = (evt.type == 'touchstart') ? evt.touches[0].pageY : evt.pageY;
...

function onDragOver(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;

  evt.preventDefault();
  const x = (evt.type == 'touchmove') ? evt.touches[0].pageX : evt.pageX,
        y = (evt.type == 'touchmove') ? evt.touches[0].pageY : evt.pageY;
...
```

Apply this change in `onDragOver` (64,65) and `onDragStart` (90,91) and it will work in mobile mode

Comment: I was a bit confused about touchstart/dragstart, but you clarified very well

Comment: Should anyone come across this, I've updated @turnip (3rror404) original pen with dehart fixes here: https://codepen.io/azerty1234/pen/ZEQpwoL